# Website acts different on different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, cross-browser

I am working on this website . It has a full screen video background and there is other javascript that is coming .

Website : [www.omod.biz/omoddemo](http://omod.biz/omoddemo)

The website behaves differently on different browsers. I dont know how I could solve it . the currect version runss smoothly on chrome , IE . works poorly on Firefox .However , does not show on opera and safari in my windows 8 PC . Ihe website again runs smoothly on safari on my Macbook .

I am trying to learn web development concepts on my own , however how does one understand how different browsers will react . And I want to make this website run smoothly on all browsers . What should be the changes ?

any type of help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: protip: use twitter bootstrap; at least while you're learning. there are careers established for designing cross-browser websites.

Comment: First, get the site to validate (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fomod.biz%2Fomoddemo%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Then come back here.

Comment: @BradChristie actually, current verions of all major browser support most basic features. I don'T really see why so many people just use monster JS libraries (jQUery, bootstrap, ...) for simple tasks that could easily be done without that huge overhead.

Comment: @JohannesH.: Because I'm jaded; I came from a world where there was Netscape and IE could go between folder view and webpage view. I also still have to support IE6. I agree though, "all major browsers" support the features--it's just _how_ they support them. IE may have margin 5px, where as chrome's is 3px, where as still firefox went with 4. (and Progo just reminded me my other favorite thing. `style` vs `-webkit-style` vs `-moz-style` vs every other variation.)

Comment: @BradChristie Default values can be changed in CSS using `*{...}`. IE6 is a point. I, personally, try to convince all customers that it doesn't really play a huge role anymore (thank god!). Don't get me wrong, there is nothing wrong with using frameworks if they're really neded. But most people nowadays don't learn the basics anymore, they just lern how to use the libraries - which leads to unnecessary bad code and "dumb" questions. Ever had somebody asking something about jQUery who didn't even know how variables in javascript work? See, that'S what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you for your responses . I will look into your suggestions and try to improve it . However , I wonder why the question was down voted . Isnt that a genuine question. I mean it could be a stupid one for many around ..Is that enough of a reason to down vote a question ? I am just trying to know the norms ..Thats it

Comment: @JohannesH.: Same could be argued about anything (I see a plethora of new developers who came of the .NET train, having never learned C\C++ [pointers, memory allocation/management/etc].) Does that make a question about array less valid because they never had to malloc? For any technology (esp. if it's "mainstream") you're going to have questions. And for SO, there are going to be a lot of repeat questions (unfortunately), but that is, after all, why it's moderated.

Comment: Agreed. ANd I indeed would tell any .NET programmers to sue the basics first, too. Otheriwse you will never be able to write high-performance, bug-free and secure (!) code.

Answer (score 3):

Different browsers support different things. Some browsers support thing other browsers don't.

In terms of CSS, make sure all of your properties have the necessary prefixes. Eg:

```
property: value;
-webkit-property: value;
-moz-property: value;
-o-property: value;
```

Also, some browsers don't support certain properties.

HTML, some browsers support certain tags.

Comment: If you stick to tags and css-properties specified in the relevant specifications (HTML4 / XHTML1.1 - HTML5 is somewhat unfinished - CSS3 (although support in some browsers isn't fully finished, most tihngs do work) - ECMA script 5.1) most current browser should do fine.

Comment: @JohannesH. Some browsers don't support all HTML5 tags. ECMA script isn't fully supported among some browsers. And some abstract CSS3 properties and selectors aren't fully supported.

Comment: True, and I did say the same in my comment. Though almost everything that was already in HTML4 / XHTML1.1 and ECMAScript 5.1 (whcih dates back to 2011) is fixed in current (! - that doesn't include IE7) browsers. I know that HTML5 is still a problem, as is CSS3. But the OP didn't use much of that, just libraries that are written by others - and reviewing those isn'T a job anybody will do on SO I guess ;) )